# How to add an Subview to a Fullscreen MPMoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, media-player

I want to add a Logo (`UIImageView`) to a fullscreen MPMoviePlayerController.

It works fine when the `MPMoviePlayerController` is not in fullscreen Mode. When i switch to full screen all added views on the `MPMoviePlayerController` removed(hidden).

Here is my code:

```
- (void)setupMPMoviePlayer{
    [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeNotifications];
    self.moviePlayer = nil;

    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [self addNotifications];

    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];


    if ([self.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)])
        [self.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];

    [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self addLogoViewAtView:self.moviePlayer.view];
}

- (void)addLogoViewAtView:(UIView *)view{        
    UIView *theView = [view viewWithTag:101];
    if (theView.superview) {
        [theView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_weiss.png"]];
    logoView.tag = 101;
    logoView.frame = CGRectMake( logoView.image.size.width - 100.0,
                                100.0,
                                logoView.image.size.width,
                                logoView.image.size.height);
    logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;    
    [view addSubview:logoView];
    [view bringSubviewToFront:logoView];
}
```

Now my question is there an alternate way to add an subview to `MPMoviePlayerController`?

I can add the logo to the application's window but this ist not so clean.

Anyone have any idea on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most propably fullscreen mode add MPMoviePlayerController view at keyWindow for an application or present a modal view controller above. So, you can try looking for the view in window.subviews or modal view controllers for moviePlayer.

Comment: have you an sample of presenting a modal viewController above? i have test it but it would not work.